# Glitchy microphone recording in AudioWorklet on Android

Tags: javascript, android, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

I would like to do some realtime processing on the microphone input (including downsampling) and crucially I want to save the input samples.

After deploying the code to production I noticed that some of the recordings I received are glitchy, some much more than others. By glitch I mean that recordings contain random periods of zero valued samples. The issue occurs on Android devices.

Luckily I got hold of a device that is able to reproduce the issue consistently (OnePlus 6). After stripping the AudioWorklet to the bare minimum I could still observe the glitchiness. This is my what my test AudioWorklet class looks like with the communication part stripped out.

```
class TestWorklet extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);

        // Allocate the buffer once in the beginning
        this.recordingBuffer = new Float32Array(sampleRate * 20);  // store max 20 sec audio
        this.recordingBufferOffset = 0;
    }

    process(inputs, outputs) {
        const input = inputs[0];
        const output = outputs[0];

        // Copy samples to the recording buffer
        if (this.recordingBufferOffset < this.recordingBuffer.length - input[0].length) {
            this.recordingBuffer.set(input[0], this.recordingBufferOffset);
            this.recordingBufferOffset += input[0].length;
        }

        // Copy input to the output
        for (let channel = 0; channel < input.length; ++channel) {
            output[channel].set(input[channel]);
        }

        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor('TestWorklet', TestWorklet);
```

And for completness sake, this is how I'm connecting the the AudioWorklet

```
import TestWorklet from './testWorklet';

start = async () => {
    let stream;
    let audioCtx;
    if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
        try {
            stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: false
            });
        } catch (e) { }
    }

    if (!stream) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }

    await audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule(TestWorklet);
    const audioSource = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    const worklet = new AudioWorkletNode(audioCtx, "TestWorklet", {
        channelCount: 1,
        channelCountMode: "explicit",
        channelInterpretation: "discrete"
    });

    audioSource.connect(worklet);

    await audioCtx.resume();
    return true;
}
```

What's interesting is, that on a less powerful Android device, I do not get these zero glitches. At least I haven't noticed any.

Does anyone have experience with this issue? Maybe I'm initializing the Worklet with sub-optimal parameters?

In the meantime, I'm trying to do an alternative implementation using the deprecated `ScriptProcessorNode` to see if it performs any better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ran into a bug in Chrome which is already reported [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1016104). If I recall correctly it's triggered when there is an AudioContext which doesn't produce any audible sound. In that case Chrome applies an optimization which means it runs the context from an internal clock instead of using the actual physical audio device.

If all of the above is true you might get away by sending a tiny signal to the audio output to keep the context running from that device.

```
const constantSourceNode = new ConstantSourceNode(audioContext);

// 0.0001 is an arbitrary value
// maybe it needs to be bigger
// maybe a smaller value works as well
constantSourceNode.offset.value = 0.0001;

constantSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
constantSourceNode.start();
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding some noise to the output did not work for me. I also experimented with oscillators with no change. Interestingly, the issue does seem somehow related as I've noticed that the period of zeroed samples is always multiples of 10ms as mentioned in that bug report.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry for the confusion. I just checked this myself. There always seems to be some initial glitch. If this works for your use case you could use a MediaRecorder instead to record the audio. It doesn't seem to be affected by this bug.

Comment: Yes this does seem to be the answer for my use case. I tested the MediaRecorder and it didn't suffer from the same issues.

Comment: If the MediaRecorder works for you, you could try using [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder) to make the MediaRecorder encode wav files.

Comment: Very interesting, I wondered how to to get the PCM data out of *audio/webm;codecs=pcm* encoded data. For my use case, since I'm doing real-time analysis of the signal in the audio worklet, I don't need to decode the MediaRecorder blob in the frontend.

Comment: Recording *audio/webm;codecs=pcm* with the MediaRecorder is only possible in Chrome. But adding a cross browser pcm encoder to extendable-media-recorder wouldn't be difficult. Feel free to open an issue on the repo for that.

Answer (score 0):

The AudioWorkletProcessor runs on the the audio thread which is timed by the soundcard and so is the process() method callback. Its meant to be called everytime its ready to process 128 samples. From my direct observation, you want to slow it down less than possible.

You might try to use the AudioworletProcessor just as a mere exporter of those 128 samples chunks, using the AudioworkletNode.port() method to talk with the main script and "export" the arraybuffer coming from the input (microphone):

```
class CustomMicProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    process (inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    const input = inputs[0];
    const output = outputs[0];

    if (input[0]) 
      this.port.postMessage(input[0]);
      
    return true;
    }
}
```

On the other side you would have a message listener:

```
customMicProcessor.port.onmessage = (samples) => { FillMicBuffer (samples.data)};
```

And then you do whatever you need to do with your data but on the main thread and not on the audio one.

I'm doing like this (downsampled recording + encoding then network delivery) in a voip web application and can record and send data perfectly from my Android device.